# Sharepoint Online Column Formatting - Show value as text

Tags: json, sharepoint, conditional-formatting

1. In a sharepoint list, I have a column named 'Hours" and I set it as
   **value**
2. I want to insert a 4 digit value like 2030, 1015, 2100, etc
3. I would like to convert this value to this format "20:30",
   "10:15", "21:00"

How can I do this without using a calculated column?
Is it possible to do it with JSON?

Regards,
Elio Fernandes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using below JSON code on your "Hours" field:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent": {
        "operator": "+",
        "operands": [
            "=substring(@currentField,0,2)",
            ":",
            "=substring(@currentField,2,4)"
        ]   
    }
}
```

For number column, change to this:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": {
    "operator": "+",
    "operands": [
      "=substring(toString(@currentField),0,2)",
      ":",
      "=substring(toString(@currentField),2,4)"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Michael, it only works if I change the type of column from Number to Single line of text. Can you make it work as a Number column type?